# Selecting and stripping img src in HTML string

Tags: python

I'm interested in stripping the s3 credientials from image tags within a block of text that is represented as a string in python.

For each  tag in the string (of which there can be many), I'd like to start at ".jpeg", end at the next instance of a quotation mark, and delete everything inbetween those locations.

For example, the following string:

```
<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJZALJ3EN746L6QWQ%2F20190430%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190430T021347Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=daf406a830d7d0f1ac2d631603b95e7e2ce0bdacd58d5a383d35f6dcd1466012" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>
```

Would become:

```
<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Why don't u split it at "?" and then get the first item from the list using index 0?

Comment: I think that I'd have to split at <img to start, right?

Comment: Is this part of a bigger xml @JasonHoward ? If yes you can use xml parsers to make your life easy!

Comment: Nope, it's not. it's basically just the contents of a short blog post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex is not the tool for the job. A more robust solution is using a HTML parser like BeautifulSoup to extract the `src` attribute of the `img` tag, and a URL parser to remove the query from the URL:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

input_str = '''<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJZALJ3EN746L6QWQ%2F20190430%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190430T021347Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=daf406a830d7d0f1ac2d631603b95e7e2ce0bdacd58d5a383d35f6dcd1466012" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_str, "html.parser")
img_url = soup.find('img')['src']
new_url = urlsplit(img_url)._replace(query=None).geturl()
soup.find('img')['src'] = new_url
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<p><img class="note-float-right" src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg" style="width: 50%; float: right;"/><br/></p><p><br/></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>
```

Edit: if you have more than one `img` tag per string, you can use:

```
input_str = '''<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJZALJ3EN746L6QWQ%2F20190430%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190430T021347Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=daf406a830d7d0f1ac2d631603b95e7e2ce0bdacd58d5a383d35f6dcd1466012" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>
                <img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJZALJ3EN746L6QWQ%2F20190430%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190430T021347Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=daf406a830d7d0f1ac2d631603b95e7e2ce0bdacd58d5a383d35f6dcd1466012" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_str, "html.parser")

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    img_url = img['src']
    new_url = urlsplit(img_url)._replace(query=None).geturl()
    img['src'] = new_url
print(soup)
```

This will update the `src` attribute of each `img` tag:

```
<p><img class="note-float-right" src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg" style="width: 50%; float: right;"/><br/></p><p><br/></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>
<img class="note-float-right" src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg" style="width: 50%; float: right;"/><br/><p><br/></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>
```

Comment: don't really want the extra tags (html and body) added to the string. How can we prevent this? Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer to address both of those issues.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the string is stored in `s`:

```
import re

re.sub('\.jpeg[^\"]+\"', '.jpeg', s)
```

This will look for areas that start with ".jpeg" and end with quotation marks and replace them with empty string.

Comment: This is represented as a string. The fact that it contains html shouldn't matter. I'll try this.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this so that we first look for the present of an image tag an only modify the contents of that?

Comment: We could define a function that checks if the string contains "<img>" or not and then perform the replacement? Is that something you are looking for? That function will just be needed to pass instead of the replacement string.

Comment: Yes, that sounds really useful!

Comment: @JasonHoward The fact that you care about html tags means that the text being html is relevant.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll have to admit that I don't understand the downsides to implementing this solution with regex.

Comment: @JasonHoward the topic of parsing html with regex has passed into stack overflow [folk lore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)

Answer (score 2):

Using `re` you can find and remove all between `?` and `"`

```
 text = re.sub('\?[^"]+', '', text)
```

Example code

```
text = '<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJZALJ3EN746L6QWQ%2F20190430%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190430T021347Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=daf406a830d7d0f1ac2d631603b95e7e2ce0bdacd58d5a383d35f6dcd1466012" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>'
expected_result = '<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>'

import re

result = re.sub('\?[^"]+', '', text)

print(result == expected_result) # True
```

---

**EDIT:** if there is text with `?` and `"` then you can add more elements in `regex`

```
result = re.sub('\.jpeg\?[^"]+', '.jpeg', text)
```

Comment: @glhr regex is not right tool for parsing HTML but this problem doesn't need to parse all HTML

Comment: What if the text in the body contains `?` and `"`?

Comment: that's correct glhr. I need some other qualifier like the img tag so that I don't pick up ? or " characters that the user wants displayed.

Comment: you can create more complex regex

Comment: Is there any way to modify this so that we first look for the present of an image tag an only modify the contents of that?

Comment: regular expressions should be used for regular languages, afaik [HTML is not one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/are-html-and-css-regular-languages)

Comment: the HTML is stored as a string within a variable. For the purposes of this problem, the html is just characters in a string.

Comment: @JasonHoward the fact that the HTML is in a string is irrelevant here. You are still trying to parse HTML tags with Regex which is not a robust solution.

Comment: @JasonHoward to check first image tag better parse HTML as in other answers. But you should say it in question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html and then use `urlparse`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse #python3
except:
    from urlparse import urlparse #python2


html = """<p><img src="https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJZALJ3EN746L6QWQ%2F20190430%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190430T021347Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=daf406a830d7d0f1ac2d631603b95e7e2ce0bdacd58d5a383d35f6dcd1466012" style="width: 50%; float: right;" class="note-float-right"><br></p><p><br></p><p> This is extra text in the body.</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for img in soup.find_all("img"):   #Find all img tags
    o = urlparse(img["src"])       #Get URL
    print(o.scheme + "://" + o.netloc + o.path)
```

**Output:**

```
https://s3beanzoid.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/media/django-summernote/2019-04-30/ec707c65-aa6d-4b81-a252-2fa1c1aef087.jpeg
```

Comment: This only shows how I can split the url and then print it in the desired form. I'm looking to cut content from the string and then save the string. Thanks for the info though. I appreciate your time.